# Where has my guide Erandur gone?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I start the quest [Waking Nightmare](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Waking_Nightmare) and I enter the temple, my guide Erandur disappears and I am left alone.

> Upon entering, Erandur will need to cast a spell upon the wall to proceed. In the next room you will face Invader Orcs, which vary in strength according to your level...

Where are the Orcs? Is this a known glitch?

Answer (score 2):

[It's a glitch.](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/52479/t1696888-waking-nightmare-quest-glitch/) Either you revert to an old savegame and try to follow Erandur immediatley after he enters the temple or when you are on the pc enter the temple and press `^` to open the console and type `prid 0024280` and `moveto player` to spawn and move Erandur near to yourself.

Comment: @agf: Thank you for the comment. I've added a short solution.

Comment: You can also use the plate glitch to walk through walls.